# Rails 3 redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How does redirecting work in rails? I find it very counter-intuitive and frustrating.

I have added view file under `/views/mymodels/custom.html.erb`

I have empty controller method:

```
def custom

end
```

I have following in routes.rb:

```
  resources :mymodel do
    member do
      get 'custom'
    end
  end
```

In my controller I try to render custom view when model has been created by:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @presentation.save
    redirect_to action: "custom"
    #format.html { redirect_to @mymodel, notice: 'Presentation was successfully created.'}
    #format.json { render json: @mymodel, status: :created, location: @mymodel }
```

This causes redirect to render a blank page. However browsing `/mymodels/[id]/custom` works fine. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't `render :action => "custom"` work either?

EDIT:

This works: `format.html { render action: "upload" }` but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you comment `format.html {...}` clause? Use it:

instead of:

```
  if @presentation.save
    redirect_to action: "custom"
    #format.html { redirect_to @mymodel, notice: 'Presentation was successfully created.'}
```

write this:

```
  if @presentation.save
    format.html { redirect_to action: "custom" }
```

Comment: Because you placed it inside the `respond_to` block. Comment this block and move your `redirect_to` outside of it and check. All should work as you expect it to.

Comment: But you have to realize that this moving out of `respond_to` has to be just for fun, no more. In a real-world application you are obliged to use responders -- it's a readable, it's a RESTful, it's a MVC-compliant approach for showing a single resource in a variety of if its representations. This way you can easily extend your, say `Product`, for representing in a json/xml/other format without adding new actions, changing routes and other stuff.